# Form_for in Ruby on Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In rails 2 form_for I have the following:

```
<% form_for :post, :url => {:action => 'create'}, :html => {:id => "new_form"} do | f |%>
```

My query is as serious in rails 4.1 ???

Comment: Try `<%= form_for`.  The `=` wasn't required in Rails 2.  For more info see [Rails Cast 208](http://railscasts.com/episodes/208-erb-blocks-in-rails-3).

Comment: In rails 4 on _form.html.erb use it for (New-create and Edit- Update). Osea code: {: action => 'create'} syntax as serious ???

Comment: I have problems with the following code, I fail to controller:

`<%= Form_for user, :as => :user, :url => {:controller => "sites/admin/users"},: html => {: id => "user_form"} do | f |% >`

Can someone help me ???

Comment: Error is : No route matches [POST] "/sites/admin/users/index"

Comment: you havn't specified action `form_for :user, url: {action: "create"}, :method => :POST do |f|`

Comment: I added your code I have the following error:

No route matches `{:action => "create", :controller => "sites/admin/ users"}`

Comment: don't add the same code, just wanted say try adding action `create` and from which action in controller you are calling this form define `@user = User.build` or `@user = User.new`, so that `form_for @user, :url => url_for(:controller => 'sites/admin/users', :action => 'create'), :method => :POST`

Comment: I have the following error:  `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Sites::Admin::Users#new` My  btn is :  `<%= link_to "Nuevo Usiario",{:controller => "sites/admin/users", :action=>"new"}%>`  and controller is : `def new     @user = User.new end`